# How to calculate the variance of importance sampling estimate

Tags: variance, markov-chain-montecarlo, hidden-markov-model, importance-sampling

I am given the following Hidden Markov Model:

$X_{k+1} = \alpha X_{k} + b W_{k+1}$

$Y_{k} = cX_{k} + dV_{k}$

Also, $V_{k}$ and $W_{k}$ are independent and iid following $N(0, 1)$

I am required to calculate the variance of importance sampling estimate of $p(y_{k})$

I have started by calculating the importance sampling estimated as shown below:

$p(y_{k}) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{1}^{N}p(y_{k}|x_{k}), \; x_{k} \; \sim \; p(x_{k})$

Up to this part it is fine. Then I have some issues with the variance. This is I have done up to now. (Ps I have proven that the estimate is unbiased)

$Var(p(y_{k})) = E\{(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{1}^{N}p(y_{k}|x_{k})- p(y))^{2}\}$
$Var(p(y_{k}) = E\{\frac{1}{N^{2}}\sum_{i}^{N}p(y_{k}^{i}|x_{k}^{i})^{2}+\frac{1}{N^{2}}\sum_{j}^{N}\sum_{m, m\neq j}^{N}p(y_{k}^{j}|x_{k}^{j})p(y_{k}^{m}|x_{k}^{m})\} - p(y_{k})^{2}$

The solution I am given is:
$Var(p(y_{k})) = \frac{E\{(p(y_{k}|x_{k})^{2}\}- p(y))^{2}}{N}$

I am not sure why the term $E\{\frac{1}{N^{2}}\sum_{j}^{N}\sum_{m, m\neq j}^{N}p(y_{k}^{j}|x_{k}^{j})p(y_{k}^{m}|x_{k}^{m})\}$ is equal to zero, except if I am doing something wrong. Does it go to zero because in the Markov model the observation (Ys) are independent between each one or can we get the same result without this assumption?